# Mocking objects in the .NET YouTube GData API

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq

I've written a service class that works with the C# GData YouTube API.  Typical use of the API involves making requests to a `YouTubeRequest` object, which calls out to a YouTube web service and deserializes the JSON-formatted response in the form of a `Feed`, `Video`, or `Playlist` instance that contains the data in the form of quite a few C# properties.

I want to unit test this service class.  In my code, the `YouTubeRequest`object is an external dependency and it needs to be mocked, but it doesn't implement any interface, so I was forced to add a layer of abstraction of my own.  This layer has methods that return these `Video` and `Playlist` types and I'm trying to use Moq to create a mock object that creates, say, a dummy `Video` instance with test data, but many of the properties on the `Video` class are read only, and these `Video`, `Playlist`, and `Feed` objects are difficult to construct, often requiring instances of other types from the YouTube Framework.

I'm quite new to unit testing, but from what I have seen of Rob Conery's videos of it, there are simply some frameworks that are not unit testing friendly, like ASP.NET Webforms.

What should I do in this situation? Am I abstracting over the `YouTubeRequest` object incorrectly?  I realize that this added abstraction layer should be very simple, but if I added a call to, say, a mapping layer, I could map the data to my own types.  Mocking an interface that returns my types would be much easier, as I could allow for get & set properties and create dummy data easily.  While the code that interacts with YouTube is relatively small, I anticipate that it will grow in size and complexity over time and so the idea of abandoning unit testing altogether is bothersome.

Comment: Do you actually need to *mock* it, or can you just create instances yourself? Mocking makes sense for services, but if you're using simple *data* classes, just build instances yourself.

Comment: You could wrap it further (complicating your abstraction layer). Alternately [impromptu-interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) might let you duck-type their classes onto your interfaces (which you could mock for testing). I haven't tried that yet, though.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean writing a fake implementation of the interface rather than mocking it? Yes, I could do that, but even if I were to write a fake implementation, how could this fake version return dummy data in the Video and Playlist objects if I can't set their properties? The service class that makes use of the YouTubeRequest object works with the Video, Playlist, and Feed objects it returns, and this is the data I'm wanting to fake in order to test the service class. The problem is strongly related to the inability to easily construct dummy Video, Playlist, and Feed instances.

Comment: @SanjeevMundluru: I mean not mocking `YouTubeRequest` at all... but I may have misunderstood your question. I haven't looked at the YouTube API... I should do so at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully generated fake dummy `Video` and `Playlist` objects and am having my mock implementation return them.  Even though certain properties on these types are read only, I found another property, called "AtomFeed" that is a get & set property.  As it turns out, all of the read only properties on the `Video` and `Playlist` objects retrieve their data from the object supplied through the AtomFeed property.  I discovered this by reading the source code for the [YouTube .NET Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/).  Ultimately, my problem sourced from my own misuse of the YouTube Library.  As a result, this answer solves only my specific problem with the YouTube Library and not general problems related to mocking an interface that must return complex, non-settable properties.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the best way to make something like this testable in C# is to have three different modules in your system: Presentation, Business, and Data.  In your case, the YouTube API is the Data module.  One way to write the YouTube Data Services that makes testability much easier is to have it simply call the API and translate the reponses (XML/JSON/etc) into POCOs (Plain-Old C# Objects).  These POCOS will probably just be classes with public properties that are mapped exactly to the schema of the API like so:

```
namespace YouTube
{
    public class Video
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int Views { get; set; }

        // etc  
    }
}
```

These should have little or no logic and are simply an internal representation of the API repose.  What this gets you is now you can easily create test data for the pieces of your app that you actually want to test: your Business layer.  You can create more complex objects out of the POCOs and you can easily do that in tests.

Then, your Presentation layer will communicate with your business layer and if you want, you can mock your business layer to test the Presentation layer.

Comment: Well, the YouTube C# library calls the YouTube web service and performs this JSON translation to PCOOs for me.  The POCOs themselves are extremely complex, and while I probably could use JSON.NET to do the mapping to my own custom Video object, this would effectively replace Google's C# YouTube Client Library with my own version.  I would manually call web service URLs and pass the data into JSON.NET.  I suppose it is a solution, but it feels like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Flip it around a little further.

While the YouTube object MIGHT already have these fields hanging off of it, assume it doesn't.  Implement an interface of something like `IFeedSource`, and give it a method that says `GetFeedForVideo (YouTubeVideo)`.  This way you get granular testability, very agnostically (`Param<YouTubeVideo>.Is.Anything`) and can return objects easily.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you are unable to mock something because it doesn't have a parameterless constructor, virtual method, interface or abstract base class you can always create a wrapper class to facilitate mocking.

Resharper makes this much easier by pressing Alt+Insert on a private member field and then choosing the "delegating members" option. Resharper will pretty much create the wrapper class for you by creating all public methods and properties, and delegating the property/method to your chosen private variable. e.g.

```
private readonly Feed<T> _feed;
```

You can then create an appropriate constructor and mark all testable methods/properties as virtual like so

```
public class GDataFeedWrapper<T> where T : Entry, new()
{
    private readonly Feed<T> _feed;

    public GDataFeedWrapper(Feed<T> feed)
    {
        _feed = feed;
    }

    public virtual AtomFeed AtomFeed
    {
        get { return _feed.AtomFeed; }
    }

    public virtual bool AutoPaging
    {
        get { return _feed.AutoPaging; }
        set { _feed.AutoPaging = value; }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Entries
    {
        get { return _feed.Entries; }
    }

    public virtual int Maximum
    {
        get { return _feed.Maximum; }
        set { _feed.Maximum = value; }
    }

    public virtual int PageSize
    {
        get { return _feed.PageSize; }
    }

    public virtual int StartIndex
    {
        get { return _feed.StartIndex; }
    }

    public virtual int TotalResults
    {
        get { return _feed.TotalResults; }
    }
}
```

Now whenever you need to return Feed, just return GDataFeedWrapper.